JDBC interpreter zippelin with dynamic username and password
I want to define an interpreter in Zeppelin for connecting to database(hive), I want every user connect to db with his username and password. I could not find anything in Zeppelin's documents. users do not have access to interpreter configuration section and I am looking for a way to get the user and password in notebook or force user to define a credential entity.
is there any way to do that?
I installed zeppelin 0.8.0
